# Custom canonical urls using sh404SEF

Tags: joomla-3.x, seo, sh404sef

Currently my site is using the sh404SEF plugin (Joomla 3.2) to add canonical urls to every page. This is working, however on the index page its outputting:

`www.example.com/?view=home`

instead of

`www.example.com`

Is there a way to update these canonical urls using the Joomla admin / sh404SEF plugin?

Comment: If the site is public can you share the url so we can look at it?

Answer (score 2):

We use sh404SEF extensively at work for large clients, so I deal with this a lot. There are times where sh404 does weird things and other times it works fine.

You should be able to purge your URL database (from within the sh404 admin) and then go back to the frontend of the site and navigate it to regenerate the site URL's. This usually fixes a lot of the oddities of sh404SEF.

Comment: I don't think I have anything to purge in my url database, when I select URL manager and click purge, it says "No records found". I have no url's setup, the canonical tag is automatically being included. I've tried setting one up but it doesn't appear to be matching my index url, since the canonical url I've provided isn't applied.

Comment: I'm sorry - I misunderstood your question. You were referring to the canonical url as output in a meta tag, correct?

Comment: The canonical url is in a link tag, with a `href=www.site.com/?view=home` and `rel="canonical"`, I'm trying to make that href=www.site.com. I was wondering if there was a way to do this through sh404SEF in the joomla admin

Answer (score 2):

I also had strange canonical tags at one point which were fixed by installing the [Canonical Plugin](http://styleware.eu/store/item/26-styleware-content-canonical-plugin) by StyleWare.

Answer (score -11):

Core Joomla SEF is not currently sufficient if you want to maximize your SEO. SEO is so much more than SEF URLs. sh404SEF, and others like it are complex but complete solutions. If your serious about SEO, you need a serious tool.

Comment: we're using sh404SEF, that's what I was asking about actually, if there was a way to modify canonical urls inside sh404SEF

Comment: Please provide more details and references about you statement.
Currently this is only a sentence in thrown in the air...

To on topic:
Every sef component slows down your site and makes it very difficult to update. Before the update you need to check the support of the new version by the component, is there any modifications to the links, you need to make beta tests and etc.

The process to update with SEF component is longer and harder than using the standard joomla SEF functionality.

Comment: SEF extensions do not slow down your site unless you have 100,000+ URLs on a $2/mo server. Like any 3rd-party extension however, of course you need to check for compatibility. There is nothing unique about SEF extensions in this regard.

Comment: -1 as the question clearly states they use sh404SEF

Comment: -1 because it's a load of nonsense and goes nowhere toward answering the question.